# How to change String to Int in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I can not print sum in this code

```
// 1. create variable 
// 2. input number in variable [but it is a string]
// 3. error to print sum
// 2 variable      
let num = [""];      
let num22 = [""];  

//add this to num  

app.post("/addNum1", function(req, res){        
    let newNum1 = req.body.newnum1;        
    num.push(newNum1);        
    res.redirect("/var1");        
});
```

add this to num22

```
app.post("/addNum2", function(req, res){

    let newNum2 = req.body.newnum2;

    num22.push(newNum2);

    res.redirect("/var2");

});
```

input number to num

```
app.get("/var1", function(req, res){

    res.render("num1", {num: num});

});
```

input number to num22

```
app.get("/var2", function(req, res){

    res.render("num2", {num22: num22});

});
```

this page is show the result of sum+sum22

```
app.get("/result",function(req,res){
    var a = parseInt("num");
    var b = parseInt("num22");
    var sum = parseInt("");
    sum = a+b;
    res.send(sum);
});
```

my port

```
 app.listen(3000, function(){
       console.log("We are in Endgame NOW!!!"); 
    });
```

describe
    when i input 2 number i want to print that sum

Comment: I'm really confused here. You want to cast a string to an integer, but your data structure is actually an array (of strings?). Do you want to sum up all the the values in the array? What do you expect `parseInt("num22")` to do?

Comment: I want to input 5 to variable num and input 2 to variable num22 and I want to print ans 7 but It show 5,2 how to fix?

Comment: Then why are both `num` and `num22` arrays? If they are strings, you can just use `var sum = parseInt(num) + parseInt(num22)` to sum them.

Comment: sry , It print NaN

`var sum = parseInt(num) + parseInt(num22);
console.log(sum);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global.num = '';
global.num22 = '';

app.post("/addNum1", function (req, res) {
    let newNum1 = req.body.newnum1;
    global.num = newNum1 ;
    res.redirect("/var1");
});

app.post("/addNum2", function (req, res) {

    let newNum2 = req.body.newnum2;

    global.num22 = newNum2;

    res.redirect("/var2");

});

app.get("/var1", function (req, res) {

    res.render("num1", { num: global.num });

});

app.get("/var2", function (req, res) {

    res.render("num2", { num22: global.num22 });

});

app.get("/result", function (req, res) {
    var a = parseInt(global.num);
    var b = parseInt(global.num22);
    var sum = a + b
    res.send(sum);
});
```

We can use `global` variable in nodejs

Comment: sry, but output is NaN